# Django Limit subquery

Tags: python, django

I wrote the following code:

```
away_fixtures = Fixture.objects.filter(Q(away=home) | Q(home=away)).order_by('-date')[:3]
tips = tips.filter(prediction__fixture__in=away_fixtures)
```

When executing the following error occurs (I use MariaDB 10.4, which does not support LIMIT in subqueries):

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: (1235, "This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")
```

When executing the following code:

```
away_fixtures = Fixture.objects.filter(Q(away=home) | Q(home=away)).order_by('-date')
tips = tips.filter(prediction__fixture__in=away_fixtures)
```

But this returns the 'tips' for all the 'away_fixtures' and I only want the for the last 3 fixtures (so limiting it to 3 fixtures). How can I achieve this without switching database engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test it so I'm not sure :

```
away_fixtures = Fixture.objects.filter(Q(away=home) | Q(home=away)).order_by('-date')[:3]
tips = tips.filter(prediction__fixture__id__in=[fixture.id for fixture in away_fixtures])
```

I think the issue comes from limiting to three the subquery `away_fixtures` so I tried to to force evaluating first query to get the ids and then the second one by filtering on these ids.

Comment: This limits to three tips and not to three fixtures

Comment: You're right.. So I think you need to force two queries : one to retrieve the ids of the last three fixtures, and then tips depending on these fixtures. I'm going to edit my answer.